# App Crashes when clicking in different TextViews very fast

Tags: android, crash, textview, fragment

I am new to android and have a Fragment with a container view (a framelayout). There are two TextViews on top of it, like tabs. Each TextView ie `txt1,txt2` adds 2 fragments ie `frgmnt1,frgmnt2` respectively. When the TextView is clicked, the corresponding Fragment is added. If clicked again, the Fragment is removed.

That part is working fine. However, but when I click in the TextView very rapidly, my app crashes and shows a "No Host" exception. Can anyone help me understand why this happens?

(Side note, the tab layout implementation is not required here).

Here is the stack trace:

```
07-04 18:22:25.600 10971-10971/integral.com.sellfie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: integral.com.sellfie, PID: 10971
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No host
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1239)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2046)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1989)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1092)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
    at integral.com.sellfie.Fragments.MemberFragment.addFragment(MemberFragment.java:319)
    at integral.com.sellfie.Fragments.MemberFragment.showFragment(MemberFragment.java:270)
    at integral.com.sellfie.Fragments.MemberFragment$3.onClick(MemberFragment.java:242)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: put your code here

Comment: Its probably because you are trying to remove the fragment even before it was added. Try disabling the view for a very short interval of time (say 300ms) after a click event has been identified.

Comment: Thanks Arpit Ratan, Vishal Patoliya for the response and sairam for proper editing . ie, i need to disable all button for 300ms.ok.i will check and will get back to you.

Comment: just testing ~code~

Comment: hi how to add the code in comment

Comment: i used this to make the delay but runonuithread showing error .the code is inside a fragment `myButton.setEnabled(false);

Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();
buttonTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                myButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}, 5000));`

Comment: @SanoopVasu - Not everyone reads comments.  It is better [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38185826/edit) and *append* any code as a update.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this will help you.You just need to change your fragments using method below.

**Note : Here I'm not using support Fragments so change the code accordingly.**

```
 //Change fragment in appropriate container
     private void changeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            if (fragment != 
        getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container)) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    //now implementing the Hack
                    if (oldFragment != null)
                        transaction.detach(oldFrag);
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
                    transaction.attach(fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    oldFragment = fragment;
                }
            }
```